# Copying Cells from Column B:D in Sheet1 to C:E in Sheet2 based on Row Number

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have a worksheet (Sheet2) where there are pasted rows at Columns B:D at different row numbers.

These row numbers actually correspond with the row numbers in worksheet (Sheet1) which are blank and I wish to paste the cells dynamically into Columns C:E.

I have the following code which allows me to copy the row from Columns B:D based on a text value = "LAW" and paste in Sheet1 as long as I know the range of the cell in Column C.

I suppose what I am looking for is the equivalent of when "LAW" is found, match the row with the one in Sheet1 and paste at Column C.  A loop is necessary as there are other instances where "LAW" is found and these cells need to be pasted at the appropriate cell range.

```
    Dim WBT As Workbook
    Dim WSD1 As Worksheet
    Dim WSD2 As Worksheet

    Set WBT = Workbooks("Invoices.csv")
    Set WSD1 = WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set WSD2 = WBT.Worksheets("Sheet2")


    Set r2 = WSD1.Range("C11")

    With WSD2
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
        For i = 1 To N
           If .Cells(i, "B").Value = "LAW" Then
                Set r1 = Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(N, "D"))
                r1.Copy r2
           End If
        Next i
    End With
```

I found it rather difficult to come up with a failsafe solution however, I hope someone can give me a few pointers as how I should go about this.

The example below demonstrates that I want to look for the rows in Sheet2 and paste them at the highlighted points in Sheet1. If there is a way of dynamically saying If Text in Column B on Sheet2 = LAW then copy that row (from Columns B to D) to the equivalent row in Sheet1.  In my example I have two instances where this occurs.

[image: Sheet2toSheet1example]

Following the success of the amendment to the script by @SJR I then struck a problem where the Workbook had many many sheets. So I modified the code and used a function to test if a sheet exists (default is Not)

```
Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet

If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
Set sht = wb.Sheets(sht)
On Error Resume Next
SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

and duplicated the code as follows:

```
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim N As Long
Set r2 = WSD1.Range("C1:C100")

With WSD2
    If Not SheetExists("Sheet1") Then
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
                For i = 1 To N
                    If .Cells(i, "B").Value = "LAW" Then
                        Set r1 = Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, "D"))
                        r1.Copy WSD1.Cells(i, "C")
                    End If
                Next i
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
    End If
End With

With WSD3
    If Not SheetExists("Sheet2") Then
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
                For i = 1 To N
                    If .Cells(i, "B").Value = "LAW" Then
                        Set r1 = Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, "D"))
                        r1.Copy WSD1.Cells(i, "C")
                    End If
                Next i
    Else
       On Error Resume Next
    End If
End With
```

Although this works fine where the workbook has 2 sheets it falls over on the second script referencing WSD3 at `N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row`with run time error '91'. By stepping through the code I find that the variable for R1 comes up with the message if you hover over the Range???? Although I tried to figure out why it is saying the variable is not set I am confused.

Comment: Could you show us a sample of the data,  what it looks like now and what it should look like after this code runs? (as few rows/columns as possible to demonstrate it please)

Comment: If they correspond to the blank rows couldn't you do `r1.Copy wsd1.cells(i,"C")`? Find would be quicker than a loop.

Comment: Not so used to the Find method @SJR but I will try to modify it to suit. I have reedited my question with a sample of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Working on it today @SJR. i'll let you know how I go.

Comment: Tried your method by including your text @SJR and although it replaces the rows where the blanks are, the intervening rows are made blank???  Sorry, I'm only a novice coder who understands the logic but not the way to write it efficiently.  However, I'm learning. Perhaps I needed a line that said If r2 is Blank (I don't know the proper syntax is - tried .Value = "" but no luck).  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this? Think you had an errant N in the line assigning r1.

```
Sub x()

Dim WBT As Workbook
Dim WSD1 As Worksheet
Dim WSD2 As Worksheet, N As Long

Set WBT = Workbooks("Invoices.csv")
Set WSD1 = WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set WSD2 = WBT.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set r2 = WSD1.Range("C11")

With WSD2
    N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
       If .Cells(i, "B").Value = "LAW" Then
            Set r1 = .Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, "D"))
            r1.Copy WSD1.Cells(i, "C")
       End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: An errant N! I should have stepped through the script @SJR. I have now tested my script with the data and confirm that this part works beautifully.

Comment: Now I have another problem @SJR (see edit). The client now has more than one worksheet in the workbook where I need to run the script to copy the rows back to the original sheet. However, I am getting an error. Any clues to why?

Comment: Well the code is only set up for the sheets specified so you would need to define other sheets or add a loop through sheets.

Comment: Yes, that is true @SJR, however, I found that I if I error trapped for the different options then it wasn't a problem.